# Why are there non-visible objects in my final render?

Tags: rendering

Have Blender on about 4 machines rendering animations.
Just spotted on one of the machines its rendering something different from the actual scene that I have setup.

[image]

Top window shows a different set of <strike>layers</strike> objects to whats actually being rendered in the rendering window below.

In my scene contents, <strike>layers</strike> objects 1-5 are not visible, but these are the ones that look like they are being rendered.

The only thing I can assume is that perhaps it might be because I did not save the document before clicking render, but I would not have expected that behaviour (you dont need to save your word document before printing it).

Can anyone confirm why this is happening?

Comment: In your screenshot, all layers are set to visible..?

Comment: The (render) visibility management in 2.81 is inconsistent, between collection visibility that has some priority on the contained object visibility (but not always), hide on render and show on render (which is not the same property). I've a case where all these properties are set to hidden and still the object is rendered.

Comment: If you parent an object to armature, it will not be visible in the render no matter what settings object has. Blender 2.90.1

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you look at the outliner, some eye-icons are faded out to indicate that certain objects are hidden.

But there's hidden and there's hidden: **hidden in the viewport** (eye-icon), and **hidden for rendering** (camera-icon).

You may paste the following code line to the *Python Console* (at the bottom of the *Scripting* view) and hit return, to make the render visibility match the viewport visibility automatically:

```
for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects: ob.hide_render = ob.hide
```

Comment: For 2.8, I had to change `ob.hide` to `ob.hide_get()`: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140483/15400

Comment: could it be more cryptic and confusing ?

Answer (score 15):

In Blender 2.8, in *Outliner* editor, there is *Filter* icon at the right side of *Search' bar, at the top.

Open the popover, and under *Restriction Toggles*, select camera icon.

Then toggle this camera icon for each object or collection to enable or disable it for rendering.

[image: blender 2.8 outliner editor - filter icons]

Comment: This is now the best of all the options here.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing this .py by [Draise14 on GitHub](https://github.com/Draise14/Addon-Match-to-Render) that saves so much time and tears:

Match Render Visibility,
https://gumroad.com/l/sMNjc

> I made these little entries to streamline the workflow of visibility and rendering, because when working with many objects, the render visibility sometimes is not the same as the viewport visibility. When you hit render, things are hidden or shown accidentally, ruining good renders - the final Render output is the important one. The viewport should reflect that.

[image]

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: done, hope that's clearer!

Answer (score 0):

To hide objects from final render, click also the camera icon next to the object. The eye is for viewport rendering, the camera is for final rendering.

Comment: in 2.8 there is no camera icon