# Problem with actual rendering and rendering view

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, particles, vertex-groups

So for the lecture im following(link below) i have to make a rabbit. I made the fur with seperate particle systems(for each part different particle system with different vertex group) like explained in the lecture. it looks good in rendered view like this:
[image]

But if i actually render the model with render image it looks like this:

[image]

It doesnt render the head fur and the eyes.
All models en meshes are enabled in rendered view, below are all my settings:

PARTICLESYSTEM:
[image]

VERTEX GROUPS:
[image]

OUTLINER
[image]

If you need any more details, tell me and i will provide.

Thanks in advance.

TUTORIAL IM FOLLOWING: https://www.udemy.com/blendertutorial/

BLENDERFILE : https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7voguv2d05979o/FluffyBunny.blend?dl=0

Comment: Would help if you uploaded your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Patdog Added it :)

Comment: Have you checked if the eyes were on separate render layers (I can't check myself, my computer can't handle such a large file, blender just crashes)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it rendering non visible objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/why-is-it-rendering-non-visible-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the particles, but Squirrel gave the idea with the eyes not being visible. Yep the whole head is hidden behind giant Metaballs. Who would have thought!? Well I guess we can all sleep easier now :)

[image]

Going to guess you have a mean machine to handle all those particles - but if you want less effort when working you can dial the Display down to something easier like 10. Keeping the display and Render at the same amount can be taxing...

[image]

p.s. Either drag the Metaballs elsewhere or switch them to visible and move to another layer or turn off the Camera for each one...

Comment: That worked thanks! But i do wonder why it doesnt render when entering rendering mode but when really rendering it does render while rendering for the metaballs is turned off?

Comment: I agree that it would be consequential if the render preview mode did show the metaballs. The viewport does have some limitations and room for improvement.