# Keyframes do not render

Tags: objects, blender-internal-render-engine, keyframes

I'm new in Blender and I have a issue  with keyframes. In 3D view I have Text objects and I set keyframes. In Image Previw in Video Sequence Editor it looks all OK(objects hide and show properly how I want), but when i render it
objects show from beginning (they are keyframed to be hidden). I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: It's likely not related to keyframes rather than to setup made for hiding. Probably you keyframed hiding objects in the 3d viewport only (eye icon). This isn't related to render at all (camera icon), see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/why-is-it-rendering-non-visible-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the outliner, if you animate the eye icon, it will controll the viewport only. You'll have to animate also the photo camera to influence the rendering. The arrow toggles the selectability of the object.

[image]