# blender 2.8: 'Object' object has no attribute 'hide'

Tags: scripting, error

Code from example:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if not ob.hide:
        continue
    ...
```

Fails on `ob.hide`:

`AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'hide'`

How to solve this issue? It seems that example was written for 2.79.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender 2.80 use a more complicated (sound and safe for code) API to deal with some attributes.

As the `object.hide` in Blender 2.79 is replaced by getter and setter function:

```py
object.hide_get() # get the hide value {True, False}
object.hide_set(True) # set hide to True
```

so, `ob.hide` needed to be replaced by `ob.hide_get()`