# A cuboid appears in the final render instead of window blinds

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, objects

THE window blinds in my scene appear with a large cuboid covering it. This is only  showing up in the render output. I tried making the window hole with a boolean modifier and without- but this cube shape is appearind either way. I'm still a learner, can someone please help?[image: this is from the rendered scene]

Comment: Go to Outliner Editor and disable this object from rendering ("camera" icon hidden by default by filtering option)

Comment: oh, that worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there non-visible objects in my final render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/why-are-there-non-visible-objects-in-my-final-render)