# render output is weird

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, blend-files, blender-id

my render output has a weird looking shape and color which is different from what I see in layout. the version I am using is 2.92. does anyone know what's wrong with it and how to fix it?

this is what i got after hitting `F12` button:
[image]

this is what I see in layout:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there non-visible objects in my final render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/why-are-there-non-visible-objects-in-my-final-render)

Answer (score 0):

You have a hidden object, "Donut2".
This only hides it in viewport, not in render. You can go into the object properties and disable render, or delete the object.
[image]