# Render result gives totally different result

Tags: rendering

I'm a total noob at Blender but I was trying to render this animation of a plastic bag turning around. In my viewport all seems normal but when I render it it looks totally different.

I'm completely lost with this. Does anyone know what I can do to change this?

Thanks in advance!!

render:
[image]

viewport display:
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Difference in Viewport/Render is often linked to modifiers or objects disabled for viewport.

Comment: Related question [Why are there non-visible objects in my final render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143192/107598)

Comment: Please provide your blend file

Comment: Is the render using EEVEE or cycles?