# Not able to render properly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-layers

I am trying to learn blender, and I've been doing a fun project based on youtube video last time. I've spend good bit of time on it but I seems to can't Render it properly
This is the project
[image]

And here is how it renders, I've been tried to find a solution but I feel like I just can't do it.
[image]

Comment: You have a few objects hidden in the viewport (eye icon on the far right in the outliner) but they might be still rendered and block your camera. Check the camera icon (render restriction): https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143192/107598

Comment: It looks like something is maybe blocking your camera. Check that nothing is in front of it (don't forget to also check for hidden items)

Comment: Omg you are right guys, I am so stupid - this was so easy. Thank you!!!