# Weird Mesh/Texture issue

Tags: rendering, mesh, texturing

I decided to make a quick animation for fun. But after a long time posing, I got to the rendering part. I got all my settings the same that I use normally. Only issue, is this is the first time I used this rig.
But I textured it correctly from what I know. The weapon textured fine, just not the rig.

My nodes
[Glove nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmkdY.png)
[Skin nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgW32.png)
[Arm (Jacket) nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVGb9.png)

The Mesh itself in the outline
[Skin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31qYH.png)
[Glove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxttE.png)
[Arm (Jacket)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bOpV.png)

The skin looks perfectly fine in render, but the Gloves and Arms have the issue.
I've looked for fixes, so far nothing has worked.

I normally render in Cycles, but I did Eevee here since it was faster.
[Viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhcuh.jpg)
[Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7omye.jpg)

***Reached Link limit; Otherwise, I would link to the docs***
RIG - MW19 Rig, deserted from the "AnimKave Repository (updated)" doc
With the Textures from MW:19 Rig, MyDude.

WEAPON - AUG A3 9MM, GrimReaper101 from the "Unofficial AnimKav Weapons Repository" doc
Textures included in download.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 0):

From answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6859/125754

Turns out there's a button to disable from render.
[image]